# Oracle Summarize data by 15 second interval

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to summarize below query by 15 second time intervals.

```
select to_char(sample_time,'hh24:mi:ss') as SAMPLE_TIME,nvl(wait_class,'CPU'),count(*) 
from gv$active_session_history 
group by wait_class,sample_time;
```

Result;

```
SAMPLE_TIME    WAITS   COUNT
-----------------------------
14:59:00        CPU     3
14:59:02        CPU     1
14:59:08        CPU     2
14:58:11        CPU     2
14:59:18        CPU     1
14:59:24        CPU     2
14:58:29        CPU     2
```

What i want is summing values by 15 second intervals. How can i make it?

```
SAMPLE_TIME    WAITS   COUNT
-----------------------------
14:59:15        CPU     8
14:59:30        CPU     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;
```

Then you can use

```
...
GROUP BY wait_class, MakeInterval(SAMPLE_TIME, INTERVAL '15' SECOND)
```

Comment: I dont want to use function. Just need to write in sql.

Comment: @johntrue Are you not able to pick the desired part from the function?

Comment: Would be `GROUP BY TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SAMPLE_TIME) / EXTRACT(SECOND FROM INTERVAL '15' SECOND)) * EXTRACT(SECOND FROM INTERVAL '15' SECOND) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND` or a bit shorter `GROUP BY TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SAMPLE_TIME) / 15) * INTERVAL '15' SECOND`

Comment: could you please rewrite in a single sql ? Then i can verify this is correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: @johntrue Sorry, SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit hack-ish but it should be what you are looking for. The lpad is just for a nicer looking result.

Edit: Forgot to group by the actual statement and not the *sample_time*. It should now group in 15 seconds intervals.

```
select 
    to_char(sample_time, 'hh24:mi:') || lpad(trunc(to_number(to_char(sample_time, 'ss')) / 15) * 15, 2, '0') as SAMPLE_TIME,
    nvl(wait_class, 'CPU') as wait_class,
    count(*) 
from gv$active_session_history 
group by nvl(wait_class, 'CPU'), to_char(sample_time, 'hh24:mi:') || lpad(trunc(to_number(to_char(sample_time, 'ss')) / 15) * 15, 2, '0')
```

Comment: It does not group by 15 second interval

Comment: It groups data of several days into one value. I don't think this is what john is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

-- can't add comments because my rep is very low

@Wernfried Domscheit gave you all the information required, I took his comments and simply "slapped" them in the group by part of your query (and obviously needed to add the bucket definition in the select statement)

The code below will allow you to check Wernfried's reply:

```
select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SAMPLE_TIME) /
EXTRACT(SECOND FROM INTERVAL '15' SECOND)) * EXTRACT(SECOND FROM INTERVAL '15' 
SECOND) *     INTERVAL '1' SECOND,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TimeBucket
,  nvl(wait_class,'CPU')
,count(*) as NbrRecords
from gv$active_session_history 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SAMPLE_TIME, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SAMPLE_TIME) /
 EXTRACT(SECOND FROM INTERVAL '15' SECOND)) * EXTRACT(SECOND FROM INTERVAL '15' 
SECOND) *     INTERVAL '1' SECOND,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), nvl(wait_class,'CPU')
ORDER BY TimeBucket DESC
;
```

HTH,

B

Comment: Pretty sure it's 15 seconds interval - I have a resultset in front of my eyes :) - but I'm not sure how to add a screenshot!

Comment: @johntrue most likely you don't have data for 1.5 Minutes because of idle sessions